# Does necessary content of same header will be duplicated in produced executable?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I use `gcc`. We know the `cpp` expands all macros definitions and include statements and passes the result to the actual compiler to create an executable file. I tested the result of `cpp` and see that some parts of header which are necessary, are included in output of `cpp` for each source file.

But I want to know if in a project I have a header that is included in multiple source files, then does the related content to that header will be duplicated multiple times in produced executable? Or there will be multiple shortcuts to them? If there will be shortcuts, I want to know why `cpp` replaces shortcuts of source files with more code and pass the result to `cc1`?

For example in a header, I have a function with name `kids`

```
int kids(){
  return 1;
}
```

and call it in `test.c` source file. The `cpp` puts the definition of `kids` in its output. But in compiled file (`test.s` which is the result of `cc -S test.c`), I only see `call kids` which is replaced instead of function definition. I call that a shortcut.I want to know what will happen for that function and its calls in executable?

Edit:

The assembly off `test.c` is:

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .globl  kids
    .type   kids, @function
kids:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $1, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   kids, .-kids
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "C Rocks + Ali!"
.LC1:
    .string "%d"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    call    puts@PLT
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    kids
    movl    %eax, %esi
    leaq    .LC1(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf@PLT
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
    .section    .note.gnu.property,"a"
    .align 8
    .long    1f - 0f
    .long    4f - 1f
    .long    5
0:
    .string  "GNU"
1:
    .align 8
    .long    0xc0000002
    .long    3f - 2f
2:
    .long    0x3
3:
    .align 8
4:
```

Comment: No, it will not. But what exactly are you referring to anyway? Are there inline function definitions that you worry about or what specifically? Can you give some example? Also what do you mean by "_shortcuts_"?

Comment: There are things that can end up in multiple translation units. (`static` namespace scoped variables, members of an anonymus namespace, `inline` function logic, ...) For the most part the contents of a header file are just there to "tell" the compiler about stuff that is not necessarily implemented in the current translation unit. Type aliases won't end up in the object files/the executable at all, in case this is what you refer to by "shortcuts".

Comment: So-called weak linking will get rid of any duplicates (and that's one of the reasons why we have the one-definition rule, so that it doesn't matter which of the duplicates the linker decides to keep).

Comment: "_For example in a header, I have a function with name kids_": What does this mean? A function declaration or a function definition? You usually (`inline` functions and C++ templates aside) have only declarations, not definitions, in header files. If the function is not inline, then you can't put the definition in a header. It will violate ODR if included in multiple translation units (`.c`/`.cpp` files).

Comment: "_I only see call kids which is replaced instead of function definition._": I don't understand what you mean here either. Please try to form a [mre] and show also the assembly output in the question.